# How to get Data from array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get data from array but I always failed.

This is the array:

```
Array
(
    [gameSpecificLoyaltyRewards] => 
    [reconnectDelay] => 0
    [lastModifiedDate] => 
    [game] => Game Object
        (
            [spectatorsAllowed:protected] => NONE
            [passwordSet:protected] => 
            [practiceGameRewardsDisabledReasons:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [gameType:protected] => RANKED_GAME
            [gameTypeConfigId:protected] => 2
            [glmGameId:protected] => 
            [gameState:protected] => IN_PROGRESS
            [glmHost:protected] => 
            [observers:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [statusOfParticipants:protected] => 1111111111
            [glmSecurePort:protected] => 0
            [id:protected] => 58513543
            [ownerSummary:protected] => 
            [teamTwo:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => zlokomatic\phpLoL\amf\game\PlayerParticipant Object
                        (
                            [accountId:protected] => 346001
                            [queueRating:protected] => 0
                            [botDifficulty:protected] => NONE
                            [minor:protected] => 
                            [locale:protected] => 
                            [partnerId:protected] => 
                            [lastSelectedSkinIndex:protected] => 0
                            [profileIconId:protected] => 548
                            [rankedTeamGuest:protected] => 
                            [summonerId:protected] => 361101
                            [selectedRole:protected] => 
                            [pickMode:protected] => 0
                            [teamParticipantId:protected] => 138114436
                            [timeAddedToQueue:protected] => 1384270965374
```

Using **PHP**, I am trying to get :

```
[gameType:protected] => RANKED_GAME
```

and

```
[accountId:protected] => 346001
```

Comment: What language? What have you tried? Can you provide a minimal example?

Comment: looks like objective c

Comment: I am trying to get with php . 

$array->game->gametype
$array[game]->gametype
all of this codes fail

Comment: you're trying to retrieve as it were an object, try `$array['game']['gametype']` ...

Comment: it says 
Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array

echo $array['game']['gametype'];

Comment: Those are object properties, not array values.  `game` is an object of class `Game`. Unless it has public methods to retrieve those protected properties, you cannot directly access them, despite the fact that `var_dump()` or `print_r()` shows them to you.

Comment: Do you have a class definition for `Game`? Does it have methods like `getGameType()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$array['game']` appears to be an `object` of type 'Game'.

`[gameType]` appears to be a protected property of this 'Game' `object`.  You may ***not*** be able to access this protected property through `$array['game']->gameType` unless 'Game' has a magic method `__get()` or an accessor method like `$array['game']->getGameType()`.

Try this to see what is available:

```
print_r( get_class_methods($array['game']) );
```

**Edit, quick demo:**

```
class Game {
  protected $gameType = 'RANKED_GAME';

  public function __get($x) {
    return $this->$x;
  }

  public function getGameType() {
    return $this->gameType;
  }
}

$array = array(
  'game' => new Game,
);
```

What you're basically seeing:

```
print_r($array);

Array
(
  [game] => Game Object
    (
        [gameType:protected] => RANKED_GAME
    )
)
```

Without available `__get()` magic method:

```
echo $array['game']->gameType;

// Fatal error: Cannot access protected property Game::$gameType
```

With `__get()`:

```
echo $array['game']->gameType;

// RANKED_GAME

echo $array['game']->getGameType();

// RANKED_GAME
```